# Copy csv data while simultaneously filling serial column

Tags: csv, postgresql, database

I've created my first postgres table and i'm trying to work out how to copy a .csv file into the table, whilst simultaneously generating a serial number number in column 1 (ID) which starts at number 1 and counts upwards (i.e. 1, 2 ,3 etc) for each row. 
I've been using the command:

```
COPY sales_table FROM '/home/perl_experiments/xmlcsv.txt' (DELIMITER('|'));
```

This attempts to copy the contents of the csv, but it seems to be placing the first column of data from the .csv into the first column of the table. I have specified the first column of the table to be a bigserial and I assumed this column would automatically fill, while the content of the csv would bypass column 1 and start filling the table from column 2. Obviously this is not the case and I have missed a vital step. Could anyone shed some light on the step I have missed? Here is a summary of the table I have created:

```
Column  Type   Not Null  Default        
ID      bigint NOT NULL  nextval('"sales_table_Entry        Id_seq"'::regclass)     [pk]        

ProdNo  bigint  

Title   character varying   

url     character varying   

Price   integer
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can specify the individual columns to fill in the `COPY` command:

```
COPY table_name [ ( column [, ...] ) ]
    FROM { 'filename' | STDIN }
    [ [ WITH ] ( option [, ...] ) ]
```

(http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-copy.html)

Therefore, specify your CSV columns explicitly in the `COPY`, leaving out the bigserials column.

Comment: for anyone that needs the actual syntax I used it is       COPY sales_table (item_number,title,url,price) FROM '/home/perl_experiments/xmlcsv.txt' (DELIMITER('|'));